# How to identify over fitting in an LSTM?

Tags: lstm, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast using the LSTM concept. I'm new to this concept. Below are my train graphs and test graphs respectively.

I've been trying to tweak the number of epochs, I wanted to know how I can judge if my model is overfitting; I'm looking back to 8 lags to identify the next forecast; what other parameters I can play with to fine tune it.

[image: Training graph of forecasts]

*The yellow line is the forecast, the blue the actual.*

[image: Testing graph of forecasts]

*The yellow line is the forecast, the blue the actual.*

Can I judge from these graphs if my model is overfitting?

Comment: In order to determine if you your model is overfitting or not, you have to compare accuracy between training and validation. Do you have the accuracies?

Comment: I agree with the above-comment that you cannot judge anything from your graphs. Overfitting happens at the "saddle" point when you observe that your training accuracy goes down and validation accuracy starts to increase. Ideally you need to train the model up to the point of  plateau in the validation set accuracy.

Comment: Hi SaTa and @Vitali, I did take a measure of errors against number of lags and the number of epochs, it gave me a clearer picture of how my model was performing. As you correctly mentioned, I did find the saddle point which helped me to identify my optimas Thank you for your time guys! Cheers!